# Why do I get an `Incorrect Padding` Error while trying to decode my base32 string?

Tags: python-3.x

I get an `Incorrect padding` error while trying to decode a BASE32 string in python using the `base64.b32decode()` function. I think I have my padding correct. Where have I gone wrong?

```
import base64

my_string=b'SOMESTRING2345'
print(my_string)
print("length     : "+str(len(my_string)))
print("length % 8 : "+str(len(my_string)%8))

p_my_string = my_string+b'='*(8-(len(my_string)%8))

print("\nPadded:\n"+str(p_my_string))
print("length     : "+str(len(p_my_string)))

b32d = base64.b32decode(p_my_string)
print("\nB32 decode : " + str(b32d))
print("length     : " + str(len(b32d)))
```

Running this code gets me

```
b'SOMESTRING2345'
length     : 14
length % 8 : 6

Padded:
b'SOMESTRING2345=='
length     : 16

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-9fe7cf88581a> in <module>()
     10 print("length     : "+str(len(p_my_string)))
     11 
---> 12 b32d = base64.b32decode(p_my_string)
     13 print("\nB32 decode : " + str(b32d))
     14 print("length     : " + str(len(b32d)))

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/base64.py in b32decode(s, casefold, map01)
    244             decoded[-5:] = last[:-4]
    245         else:
--> 246             raise binascii.Error('Incorrect padding')
    247     return bytes(decoded)
    248 

Error: Incorrect padding
 ​
```

However, if I change `my_string` to `b'SOMESTRING23456'`, I get the code working perfectly with the output -

```
b'SOMESTRING23456'
length     : 15
length % 8 : 7

Padded:
b'SOMESTRING23456='
length     : 16

B32 decode : b'\x93\x98IN(i\xb5\xbew'
length     : 9
```

Comment: 14 characters can't encode any base32 input.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - it is 16 characters when i pass it to the `base64.b32decode()`. What am I missing? 14 char = 70 bits. I need to make it 80 bits = 10 bytes that can accommodate 16 base32 characters.

Comment: No, 8 characters is 40 bits. The next 5 characters can encode a further 24 bits (plus space for one more bit). An additional 6th character can only add 5 more bits, not enough for a whole byte, so you will never have a 14-character base32 string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no legal 14-character base32 strings. Any remainder beyond modulus 8 can only be 2, 4, 5, or 7 characters long, so padding must always be 6, 4, 3 or 1 `=` character, any other length is invalid. Since a remainder of 6 characters is not a legal base32 encoding, the `base32decode()` function can’t do anything but reject the invalid `5` character used instead of a valid `=` padding character.

A base32 character encodes 5 bits and a byte is always 8 bits long. That means that you don’t need padding for inputs of a multiple of 5 bytes (5 times 8 == 40 bits, which can be encoded cleanly in 8 characters).

Any remainder over a multiple of 5 is encoded thus

- 1 byte = 8 bits: 2 characters (10 bits)
- 2 bytes = 16 bits: 4 characters (20 bits)
- 3 bytes = 24 bits: 5 characters (25 bits)
- 4 bytes = 32 bits: 7 characters (35 bits)

14 characters would hold 70 bits, which is 8 bytes (64 bits) with 6 bits to spare, so character 14 would carry no meaning!

So for any base32 string with a remainder of 1, 3, or 6 characters you will always get an `Incorrect padding` exception, regardless of how many `=` characters you add.

Note that the last character in a remainder encodes a limited number of bits so is also going to fall in a specific range; for 2 characters (encoding 1 byte) the second character only encodes 3 bits with the last 2 bits left at 0, so only A, E, I, M, Q, U, Y and 4 are then possible (so every 4th character of the base32 alphabet, A-Z + 2-7). With 4 characters the last character represents just one bit, so only A and Q are legal. 5 characters leaves 1 redundant bit so every second character can be used (A, C, E, etc) and for 7 characters and 3 redundant bits, every 8th character (A, I, Q, Y).

A decoder can choose to accept all possible base32 characters as at that last position and just mask off the bits that still are needed, so for 2 characters a `B` or `7` or any of the other invalid characters can still lead to a successful decode, but then there is no difference between `AA`, `AB`, `AC` and `AD`, all 4 will only use the top 3 bits of the second character and all 4 sequences decode to the hex value `0x00`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. It took me a while to realize that base32 encoding and decoding are not 100% reversible. Several base32 strings decode to the same value.Base 32 numbers 77,76,75,74 (with padding) all decode to 0xFF

Comment: @LordLoh.: Base32 is fully reversible. But you can't just generate random characters and hope to decode that to something. Two characters encode just 10 bits, and the decoder can choose to tolerate the additional bits; normally only `7A`, `7E`, `7I`, `7M`, `7Q`, `7U`, `7Y` and `74` are valid base32 sequences. The first `7` encodes all `1` bits, so `11111`, and for the next character only the first 3 bits matter; for `77` through to `74` the first 3 bits are all `111`, only the last two bits change (`11`, `10`, `01` and `00`).

Comment: @LordLoh.: you'd need another 2 whole characters to be able to encode another full byte (at which point the last character only covers 1 bit of information!).

Comment: I think I understand better now. `decode ( encode ( bitstream) )` will always give me the `bitstream`. But not so (uniquely) for `encode ( decode  ( conjured up B32))`. Encode maps from all possible binary streams to a set of legal B32 strings. But the exhaustive set of B32 strings (legal and not legal) cannot map to a binary stream uniquely.

Comment: @LordLoh.: exactly, and that's because base32 characters represent 5 bits at a time, but the binary value that is encoded comes in 8-bit blocks (bytes), so for anything other than 5 bytes / 8 characters there are going to be some extra bits that are not used.